# Keyboard shortcut in Nemo to open terminal in active folder

Tags: nemo

Nautilus has the ability to [assign a keyboard shortcut to open a terminal at the current folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here).

Is this possible in Nemo (I have version 2.6.7, running on Linux Mint 17.2)?

Comment: (As I don't have enough points, I cannot add a comment... :$ So, I have to type a new answer.) I can confirm that the above mentioned method answered by John Lindgren still works on Ubuntu 19.04 with Nemo 3.8.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but not obvious how to do it:

- Create the file ~/.gnome2/accels/nemo:

  ```
  $ mkdir -p ~/.gnome2/accels
  $ touch ~/.gnome2/accels/nemo
  ```
- Then add the following line in that file (replace "F4" with whatever shortcut you want to use):

  ```
  (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "F4")
  ```

This worked for me with Nemo 3.6.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=225682#p1197133

Comment: Thanks! Works in Ubuntu 20.04 (requires a restart of nemo to start working).

Comment: This method doesn't work in Nemo 4.8.6

Answer (score 3):

In Nemo, a terminal is just part of the package!  No funny shortcuts needed!  **:-)**

[image: Nemo with terminal active]

Just ensure the plug-in is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-terminal
```

Which will ensure you have a terminal ready at all times.

**If you want additional terminals on top of the standard one,** just right-click any directory and choose the menu-item <kbd>Open in Terminal</kbd> and it'll open an additional terminal.  Continue doing this for more terminal windows.  **;-)**

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: The built-in terminal is fine for some workflows, but I very often start my work by navigating to a folder in Nemo then launching a couple of terminals to run, e.g. iPython and vim. So I really need a separate terminal window.

Comment: @LondonRob: Answer edited.  See **bold** section.

Comment: Thanks for the update! The right-click method is what I currently use. It's a keyboard shortcut for this very action which I'm after!

Comment: Looks like nemo-terminal is not available anymore.

Comment: Yes. `nemo-terminal` isn't available